# What can I do so my "HOME" link in my navigation bar is selected when the user is at HOME page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using HTML5 & CSS3 on my MVC 3 project and I am having problems with my navigation bar.

This is how my navigation bar:

[image: My navigation bar]

The pink submenu appears when a user hover over the links. And its all done with CSS3 no javascript at all.

What I want to do is that when someone visit my webapplication "HEM" which is "HOME"  it should automaticly be selected like the picture. And when the user navigate to lets say "ADMIN" same happens there the pink submenu is always there.

How can I be able to do that?

This is my CSS:

```
ul#nav {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  width: 961px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  /* gradient */
  background: url(../../Content/img/nav-tile.gif) repeat-x;  
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: right;
  font: bold 12px verdana,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 35px;
}

/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE */
ul#nav .current a, ul#nav li:hover > a  {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #330000;
  background: #dd006b;  
}

/* THE SUBMENU LIST HIDDEN BY DEFAULT */
ul#nav  ul {
  display: none;
}

/* WHEN THE FIRST LEVEL MENU ITEM IS HOVERED, THE CHILD MENU APPEARS */
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 961px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  /* gradient */
  background: #dd006b url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x;      
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dd006b), to(#a1014e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dd006b,  #a1014e);
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #dd006b, #a1014e); 
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 12px verdana,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2 30px 0 0;
  background: #dd006b url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x;  
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dd006b), to(#a1014e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dd006b,  #a1014e);
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #dd006b, #a1014e);  
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

and my layout in MVC for the "HEM" aka "HOME" is following:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("HEM","Index","Home")
<ul></ul>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's built dynamically, doesn't it add the .current class to the li anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MVC3, but it's possible using Javascript/jQuery.
Here an example using jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/MFhqW/

```
$('a[href="'+window.location.href+'"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the anchors are relative links... you might want to add statements for both absolute and relative links.

Comment: Its no different, it will be displayed as <a href="/">Home</a>